# how to apply where clause in generic type list in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

i have a generic method like this

```
 public IList<T> Get(KendoGridFilterSort.FilterContainer filter)
    {
        List<T> list = null;
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _entities.Set<T>();
        list = dbQuery
        .ToList<T>();
        return list;

    }
```

when in inititate the class of this method with specific object i got the full list of records.
but i want to pass some filter thorough  parameters in this method to filter records accordingly . for this i have  class name KendoGridFilterSort.FilterContainer that contain all the filter with field name, operator and values
i want to use that filters with this generic method , my problem is i cannot use 
this statement for example

```
persons.Where(p => p.Name == name && p.Surname == surname).ToList();
```

so is there any possibility that i could apply my filter on this generic list ?

Comment: You need to show us the code for `KendoGridFilterSort.FilterContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

You should force your `T` class implement `IEntity` interface with properties, that you want to `filter`:

```
public interface IEntity
{
   string Name {get;set;}
   string Surname {get;set;}
}

public class Repository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    public IList<T> Get(KendoGridFilterSort.FilterContainer filter)
    {
        return _entities.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Name == filter.Name && x.Surname == filter.Surname).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a filter as an Expression tree as you're using `IQueryable<T>`

```
public IList<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    List<T> list = null;
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _entities.Set<T>();
    dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(filter);
    list = dbQuery.ToList<T>();
    return list;
}
```

Although its unclear what `KendoGridFilterSort.FilterContainer` is doing